# How to unlock Christmas-themed summoner Icons

Tags: league-of-legends

Considering [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/45701/39345) questions is quite outdated, as well as its answers, I decided to open a new, more targeted one.

As some of you may know in League of Legends has been released a set of Christmas-themed **summoner icons** that can be unlocked by players who fulfil **certain criteria**, such as never having been banned or having entered a queue with a 5-man-team during the Christmas period.

So, what are the **exact conditions** required for **every one** of the available icons?

Comment: How long are these icons obtainable for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Riot never officially published the details on how to unlock them. However if we are to believe the various rumours around related forums and the internet, the image below is a very nice compiled list of hints. I myself can confirm the accuracy of at least the first hint as I got it only days ago.

[image]

*Clarifications:*

**Doran's Wreath Icon:** Enter a queue as part of a 5-member premade team.
**Stocking Blades Icon:** Buy RP as a gift for a friend.
**Trimmed Turret Icon:** Buy a Champion as a gift for a friend.
**Reindeer Urf Icon:** Buy a skin as a gift for a friend.
**Holiday Nashor Icon:** You will have this earned at the beginning of the Snowdown period if your account has never been banned (or received a warning?)
**Shopkeeper Icon:** This icon will be awarded at the end of the Snowdown so no-one is really sure about the conditions. Most seem to agree though that based on the hint one must have unlocked a certain amount (perhaps even all) of the other 5 Snowdown summoner icons in order to earn this one.

Comment: I question the accuracy of the Holiday Nashor Icon. My account has never been been banned or received a warning or even been reported as far as I know (though of course it is possible that it has been reported and just not enough to warrant action) and I did not receive this icon.

Comment: @AdamP To be honest I am in a similar position, however most people seem to agree about the requirement. Perhaps it even counts times you have been merely judged by the Tribunal as a violation. Or maybe both of us received a short ban during a time we were not playing.

Comment: If this were the case wouldn't we have received an email informing us of the ban or warning? Even if it were during an inactive period we should have records of it.

Comment: To have "Holiday Nashor Icon" you musn't have been judged guilty by the tribunal ;-)

Comment: can u still get these summoner codes?